# remove a column when the column name is empty in R

Tags: r, filter

I was running a procedure to make the first row as column names. Since one value is `NA` one column has become empty. Here is the example.

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("a","b","c","d",NA),
                 var2 = c(1,2,3,4,NA),
                 var3 = c(NA,7,8,9,10))

> df
  var1 var2 var3
1    a    1   NA
2    b    2    7
3    c    3    8
4    d    4    9
5 <NA>   NA   10

df1 <- df %>%
  janitor::row_to_names(row_number = 1) 

> df1
     a  1 NA
2    b  2  7
3    c  3  8
4    d  4  9
5 <NA> NA 10
```

How can I remove when the column name is empty?
The desired output would be:

```
  > df2
         a  1 
    2    b  2  
    3    c  3  
    4    d  4  
    5 <NA> NA
```

Comment: If `row_to_names` is from `janitor` package, add that library to your post? Also, could you try `df1[!is.na(names(df1))]` to remove NA columns?

Comment: this solution works well, if you can post this, I will mark it.

Comment: I would argue that the proper response should have been a letter to the maintainer telling him/her/it that columns should NOT be allow to be R NA's.

Comment: Base R allows it as well, but converts the missing value to a character string, "NA" (just as 1 is converted to "1"). Try `names(df) <- df[1, ]` followed by `names(df)` and `df$"NA"`. To remove the column `df <- df[, names(df) != "NA"]`.